# How to post Images and video on facebook in iPhone

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, ios4, sdk

I want to post Images and Video on my facebook wall. Some of the tags are deprecated which we are using for posting data through ios sdk of facebook.What are the new tags for posting images on facebook ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this links.

These links are for posting video and photo in your facebook wall and it is updated too..

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/video/